# How to generate samples from an arbitrary continuous pdf?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, random, distributions

If I define an arbitrary pdf p[x_] for a arbitrary-dimensional continuous variable x, how can I use Mathematica to create a function that will return a set of n random samples of x with distribution p?

An answer that assumes p[x_] and all of its derivatives are smooth and continuous would be helpful, but an answer that does not assume that would be even better.

Comment: Depends. Does `RandomVariate[]` work with a `ProbabilityDistribution[]` built from your PDF? You can always do rejection sampling otherwise.

Comment: @J.M.  That worked.  Thank you.  (This is where it would be nice if the MMa documentation had more practical examples of using functions in conjunction.)

Comment: Consider answering your own question if you did figure things out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for the solution, J.M.

```
(* create an example pdf *)
f[x_] := Exp[-x^4 + x^2];
normf = NIntegrate[f[x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}];
p[x_] = f[x]/normf;
Plot[p[x], {x, -2, 2}]

(* How to generate samples from p[x] *)
pd = ProbabilityDistribution[p[x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}];
d = RandomVariate[pd, 100000];
Histogram[d, 100]
```

[image: i1]

[image: i2]

Comment: `Method -> Normalize` can be a useful setting at times.